# Ember CLI - Windows - Ember server not working throws no errors

Tags: windows, ember.js, npm

I am usually on linux machine but I'm trying to set up a development environment on windows.

I supposedly have everything set up and I'm able to create projects on ember cli and install packages via Bower and NPM.

However when I initiate the ember server and try to access the Serving address it nothing seems to go wrong on the console:

```
D:\www\ember_base>ember server
version: 0.0.40
   Livereload server on port 35729
   Serving on `http://0.0.0.0:4200`
   Build successful - 891ms.

Slowest Trees                  | Total
-------------------------------+----------------
TreeMerger (vendor)            | 175ms
TreeMerger (appAndDependencies) | 136ms
TreeMerger (stylesAndVendor)   | 132ms
CustomStaticCompiler           | 105ms
```

An that's it no errors, and when I try and access  on Chrome I just get an ERR_ADRESS_INVALID:

>

```
 The webpage at http://0.0.0.0:4200/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Error code: ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID
```

Comment: did you try localhost:4200? 0.0.0.0 is to make sure it can be accessed from other pcs as well....

Answer (score 0):

for windows try to install with ember CLI by following command and then create your ember project:

Install ->`npm install -g ember-cli-windows`

Create your project -> ember new myproject